# Is there a way to remove "Project" in every Jenkins job names when clicking on Build?

Tags: jenkins, build, project, jobs

When clicking on a certain Jenkins job, the title of the job starts with "Project". Suppose I have a job named "Demo Job", and clicking on the job itself will result in displaying "Project Demo Job". Is that a standard Jenkins way of assigning name to a job or it can be  configured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it depends on the job that you configure. 
Example : 
If you create a freestyle project , then it would display `Project <Your jobname>`
If you create a pipeline project , then it would display `Pipeline <Your jobname>`
 This would not impact anything and also when you access your jobname with `${env.JOB_NAME}`, then it would return you your jobname without appending anything.

Comment: also, i would like to ask whether there is any workaround for removing that "Project.." from job when selecting in the Dashboard. I was curious to know whether it was possible, for implementing as a business requirement.

Comment: I dont think its configurable